# Considering ATK Framework

Tags: php, frameworks

Has anybody used the ATK Framework?  It is claimed to be geared toward developing apps for business use.  Manipulating data, knowledge bases, etc...   This is what I primarily develop (on the side-for my own use).  The site hasn't given me a great overview of why it may be better than other frameworks.

What are your thoughts / experiences with this product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let me say that I've been using ATK for only few days now, while my co-workers have been using it for almost 6 months.
ATK Framework is really, excellent framework - but with quite special purpose.
If your looking for framework to help you build Administration panel - ATK will save you loads of time. You only have to write few lines of code to build complete and really good administration panel.
The only thing I didn't like about this framework is that you can't really control everything (things going under the hood) and the fact that it doesn't have support for UNIX TIMESTAMPS (I've tried to generate date field but it didn't want to accept time stamp so I had to change some things, add a class).
ATK community is really great, and with my co-worker helping me - I've learned lots of things about this framework in only 3 hours.
**HOWEVER** if you're looking for universal framework to code your whole site - you might want to avoid this one.
Personally, I'm going to go (really soon) for ATK+Zend Framework combo - ATK for backend and Zend for frontend.

Answer (score 3):

ATK is a great framework. I used it to create [MySHI](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/myshi/index.php?title=Main_Page). An open source project I spent some time on back in 2008. I've not yet built anything with Django but have worked through the tutorial once or twice.

ATK is similar to Django's admin interface. Django is a better general framework. But I found ATK to be a more thorough business logic framework. Django's admin interface is only meant to be rough back end interface for managing a websites content it's original design isn't meant to be the front end for a large database driven website.

For creating a web interface to a data centric database (out of the box) ATK seems to better match what is necessary to create a complete UI. The biggest problem with them both is when you will want to do things that aren't part of the framework. Either one will some times seem to fight you from doing things you know you should be able to do.

ATK Cons

- Small Dev Team (But reasonably responsive)
- Lack of Marketing (no buz)
- Small User Base (Getting help)
- PHP (Python is the current craze but there isn't anything wrong with PHP)
- Documentation (Limited but after working through the tutorial most of it is API after that.)

If I were to start a project today I might pick either one. If the project were small with few table relationships and I knew ahead of time a custom user ui was necessary I'd pick Django. Think a simple personal bank register. If I were to start a project with many table relationships and the database admin was the user interface then I'd pick ATK. Think customer management with invoicing. If I were to start a highly complex project where I might need to do some things not thought of by the framework architects then I'd pick a more general and open framework like Pyramid or Ruby on Rails (still trying to answer this one myself). Think electronic medical record.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best framework that i ever used..it handles all CRUD function..so it just use a few line of code to create a simple web based system..this framework will drive you to learn what all developers needs to build a great system..either you to want intergrate with other tools..it depends..i put my believe that without work hard you cant be the best..this is truth because i got failed in programming paper..then NOW! i'm developer!

Answer (score 0):

I just download ATK Framework a few days back ago and now finishing one of the modules in my current software project to be presented to my client this week. I could say ATK save my time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the ATK Framework on four projects now and have been pleased with the framework in general.  It is excellent for rapid application development and allows us to turn around fully functional business process sites in a matter of weeks.  We have sucessfully integrated third party controls like the Aurigma Image Uploader to handle complex image manipulation and management, used the framework against databases with several million records per table, and scaled the data export routines to hundreds of thousands records at once.  The biggest issue we have had with the ATK Framework has been documentation and specific examples for things we need to do that do not fit in the normal ATK use cases.  We have contracted with iBuildings a time or two to have very specific changes made to support our project and they have been very responsive and thurough in their work.  We have used other Frameworks as well, including Zend Framework and .NET - and while each have their own strengths I can tell you that I have not seen a faster way to create a fully functional application than with ATK, but you do sacrifice some control over exactly how things are done under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

We use the atk-framework in work and I must say this is the worst Framework I've ever used.
Nothing is like in other Framework - nothing works like it should be and the documentation - btw. What documentation?

This is not only bad it is totally unuseable

Comment: This is a rant and not an answer. Try and be constructive.